# How can I apply a format style to all datatables in a R notebook

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I learnt recently that I can modify how a `datatable` from package `DT` looks by using the `formatStyle` function

```
options(digits.secs=6)
library(data.table)
d = data.table(x = 1:10,time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00.123'))
library(DT)
datatable(d, options=list(pageLength = 3, 
                          lengthMenu = c(2, 12, 18),
                          searching= FALSE))%>%
formatStyle( ., columns=0, target= 'row',color = 'black', backgroundColor = 'yellow', fontWeight ='bold', lineHeight='70%')
```

Now say I have 10 of those tables, can I apply those properties globally in the notebook ?

I know I can write some `css` directly in the notebook body, but it does not seem to work with the above properties

```
<style>                     
    table {                 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }                       
</style
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

This is not a most elegant solution but you could write a wrapper function:

```
my.style <- function(.) formatStyle(., columns=0, target= 'row',color = 'black', backgroundColor = 'yellow', fontWeight ='bold', lineHeight='70%')
```

and then:

```
options(digits.secs=6)
library(data.table)
d = data.table(x = 1:10,time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00.123'))
library(DT)
datatable(d, options=list(pageLength = 3, 
                          lengthMenu = c(2, 12, 18),
                          searching= FALSE))%>% my.style()
```

Or around data.table in a similar manner.

Comment: Well yes but that's the same thing, you are just removing characters that I have to paste everytime